# Reuse Zend 2 form with captcha for editing

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, captcha

I have a form for some element creation with captcha. 
It works fine.

But I want use this form in Admin page too, and there should be no captcha.
When I try to submit form I have an error

```
["captcha"] => array(1) {
  ["isEmpty"] => string(36) "Value is required and can't be empty"
}
```

How can I reuse this form without captcha? Is there another method without  extending another new form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just create Filter

```
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class FreeLessonFilter extends InputFilter
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->addElements();
}

protected function addElements()
{

    $captcha = new Input('captcha');
    $captcha->setRequired(TRUE);

    $this->add($captcha);

}
}
```

And than use it in Admin page controller, but not in Index page

```
    $this->defaultForm = new FreeLessonForm();
    $filter            = new FreeLessonFilter();
    $filter->get('captcha')->setRequired(false);

    $this->defaultForm->setInputFilter($filter);
```

By default it required, but in admin - not.

Comment: You could also just remove the Captcha element from your form from your admin page controller.

Comment: @AdamLundrigan, i haven't this element in admin page view, but it's triggered anyway when I call $form->isValid(). You can try.

Comment: Not displaying it on the client side view isn't the same as removing it from the form.  You have to remove it from the form by calling `$form->remove('element-name');` before you validate the form.  You may also need to remove the input filter for it by calling `$form->getInputFilter()->remove('element-name');`